# Can any reduced residue system be generated by two polynomials?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $S_m=\left\{r_1,\ldots ,r_{\phi (m)}\right\}$ be a reduced residue system modulo $m$. The question is: For every $m$ does there exist two
cuadratic polynomials $f,g\in \mathbb{Z}_m[x]$ such that $$\left\{f(1),\ldots ,f\left(\frac{\phi (m)}{2}\right)\right\}$$and$$\left\{g(1),\ldots
,g\left(\frac{\phi (m)}{2}\right)\right\}$$ form a partition of $S_m$? In other words: is it always posible (for all $m$) to find $f,g$ polynomials
of degree 2 such that $S_m=\left\{f(1),\ldots ,f\left(\frac{\phi (m)}{2}\right),g(1),\ldots ,g\left(\frac{\phi (m)}{2}\right)\right\}$ with $f(i)\neq
g(j)$ for all $i$ and $j$?

For example, for $m=7$ we give $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=-x^2$ and thus: $$\{f(1),f(2),f(3)\}=\{1,4,2\}$$ and $$\{g(1),g(2),g(3)\}=\{6,3,5\}.$$
Therefore $S_7=\{1,4,2,6,3,5\}=\{f(1),f(2),f(3),g(1),g(2),g(3)\}.$

I have manually verified this up to $m=25$ and it seems very pausible. I'm not expecting a direct answer (although a direct answer would be great),
but if there has been work in this area, a reference would be great. Thanks.

Comment: For $m$ a power of an odd prime, it is true; your example with $m=7$ generalizes easily. The general case shouldn't be much harder.

Comment: I don't understand, how would you generalize it? For $m=13$ $f(x)=x^2$ and $-f(x)$ does not work, in fact they both generate the same thing.

Comment: $f(1)=1$ $f(2)=4$ $f(3)=9$ $f(4)=3$ $f(5)=12$ $f(6)=10$ and the other generates $-f(1)=12$ $-f(2)=9$ $-f(3)=4$ $-f(4)=10$ $-f(5)=1$ $-f(6)=3$

Comment: Dear Alejandro: Of course. I did not claim that the exact same choice of polynomials works - it doesn't, as you remark. The reason is that $-1$ is a square mod $13$. But if you choose any non-square mod $13$, say $a$, then the polynomials $x^2$ and $ax^2$ will do the job. This is the same reason for which $x^2$ and $-x^2$ work for $m=7$, because $-1$ is not a square mod $7$.

Comment: Thank you very much, just one last question: for and odd prime modulus $x^2$ and $ax^2$ work perfectly, but for a modulus $p^n$ these polynomials don't work even if $a$ is a none square. From what I understand $x^2$ generates the quadratic residues and $ax^2$ generates the quadratic nonresidues for a prime modulus; this however does not happen for a power of an odd prime.